# Loss is Nan even with clipvalue set and Adam optimizer

Tags: neural-network, keras

I'm currently doing [this task from kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/wordsforthewise/lending-club/tasks?taskId=2302).

I've normalized my data with the minmax scaler and fixed the dummie variable trap by removing one column to every dummie variable I created.

Here is the first row of my training data:

```
array([0.45822785, 0.41137515, 0.41953444, 0.01045186, 0.00266027,
       0.13333333, 0.        , 0.02342393, 0.62156863, 0.16778523,
       0.09375   , 0.        , 1.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
       0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
       0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
       0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 1.        ,
       0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
       0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
       0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
       0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
       0.        , 0.        , 1.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
       0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 1.        , 0.        ,
       0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
       0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
       0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
       0.        , 0.        , 1.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
       0.        , 0.        , 1.        , 1.        , 0.        ])
```

This is the model I'm using:

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Activation,Dropout
from tensorflow.keras import optimizers
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping

early_stop = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', mode='min', verbose=1, patience=25)
optimizer = optimizers.Adam(clipvalue=1)


model = Sequential()

# https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/181/how-to-choose-the-number-of-hidden-layers-and-nodes-in-a-feedforward-neural-netw

model.add(Dense(units=85,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Dense(units=42,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Dense(units=42,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Dense(units=1,activation='sigmoid'))

# For a binary classification problem
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer)

model.fit(x=X_train, 
          y=y_train, 
          epochs=600,
          validation_data=(X_test, y_test), verbose=1,
          callbacks=[early_stop]
          )
```

As stated, I'm using a clipvalue of 1 with the adam optimizer which was what was recommended on [this](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/68331/keras-sequential-model-returns-loss-nan) and [this](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/67047/loss-being-outputed-as-nan-in-keras-rnn) posts.

Despite that, the output I'm getting is the following:

```
Epoch 1/600
8664/8664 [==============================] - 7s 810us/step - loss: nan - val_loss: nan
Epoch 2/600
8664/8664 [==============================] - 7s 819us/step - loss: nan - val_loss: nan
Epoch 3/600
8664/8664 [==============================] - 7s 818us/step - loss: nan - val_loss: nan
Epoch 4/600
8664/8664 [==============================] - 7s 824us/step - loss: nan - val_loss: nan
Epoch 5/600
8664/8664 [==============================] - 7s 805us/step - loss: nan - val_loss: nan
Epoch 6/600
8664/8664 [==============================] - 7s 800us/step - loss: nan - val_loss: nan
Epoch 7/600
8664/8664 [==============================] - 7s 833us/step - loss: nan - val_loss: nan
Epoch 8/600
8664/8664 [==============================] - 7s 821us/step - loss: nan - val_loss: nan
Epoch 9/600
8664/8664 [==============================] - 7s 806us/step - loss: nan - val_loss: nan
Epoch 10/600
8664/8664 [==============================] - 7s 813us/step - loss: nan - val_loss: nan
```

Comment: Have you checked your data for null values?

Comment: I've removed all rows with null values on the preprocessing phase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It ended up being that I didn't save my changes upon removing NaN values...

Changed this:

```
df.dropna()
```

To this:

```
df = df.dropna()
```

Comment: You can also do `df.dropna(inplace=True)`